# Handling errors with Gdiplus::Image

Tags: c++, image, error-handling, gdi+

How do you handle errors when using `Gdiplus::Image::FromFile()`? I purposely had it try to read a file that didn't exist.
It didn't throw any exception, or return NULL.

I could check if the file exists before hand, but what if the file is not a valid image file, or something else goes wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In examples to GDI+: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx so, you should verify that Image::GetLastStatus() == OK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. They should really document that in Image::FromFile().

Comment: As of 2017 this answer is not helpful any longer: the GetLastStatus() method is not static any longer, so calling it on a NULL pointer generates access violation...

Comment: It is strange that GetLastStatus() is not static, so if a NULL pointer is returned from FromFile()/FromStream() there is no way to check what may go wrong... Though in most cases returned NULL means that GdiplusStartup() hasn't been called.